# How to import the data from a Google Public Data Explorer into SharePoint 2010 out-of-box charts

Tags: web-part, import, data, chart

using the new Google PDE I was wondering if there was a way of importing the data into my nicely formatted Chart Web Parts in sharepoint 2010.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no such thing as nicely formatted charts in SharePoint. Your options are:

1. Rely on the Chart Web Part, which actually connects to either an
   existing SharePoint list, or Excel worksheet and similar to how it
   works in Office, it will allow you to visualize content or your custom Web Part using some jQuery libraries, such as FLOT.
2. Rely on actual importing the content from other sources into Excel, and use either PerformancePoint for advanced charting, or directly Excel 2010/2013 REST API to visualize external data, while the actual excel file is hosted in a SharePoint library, but still capable of reaching out (either to external data, or local sources such as lists/databases). You do need Excel Services, which translates into Enterprise edition. Alternatives are also to consider BDC to connect to external data and use the External list concept for real-live feeds, which of course then you would need to get back to the Chart web part.

Comment: Hi... Thanks for the reply. I have about 200 formatted charts from the chart web part and these look good... After a lot of customisation ! I have excel services and have a few charts in that too... But my question was on pulling the raw data from the google public data explorer only.

Comment: And I'm looking to get BDC soon. That's a good point... Have PowerPivot but no live SQL enabled. Using enterprise 2010 I should have said.